# How can I get a software that worked on Vista to work on 7? Compatability doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, compatibility

Ok I have a dj software that I really like, that used to work on my desktop with Windows XP, and a laptop with Vista. But it wont open on 7. I have tried compatibility mode, and it wont work. Is there anyway it can work? Please help.

The manufacturer doesn't make this anymore or doesn't upgrade, if they do I don't know, there's no website that works, and I didn't bother to email them, but basically I don't think they really do much with this. The software is called 2710 Dj, and u can still find it online, some websites offer to download it.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can try installing Windows XP inside of VirtualBox. This is free virtualization software - it will let you run almost any Windows XP program that doesn't require specialized hardware. More information about where to get it and how to use it at http://www.virtualbox.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the software and start over following this guide.

Here is how to install software or drivers on Vista/W7 that are designed for XP

1. Right click on the setup.exe file for the software you are trying to install and select properties, if there is an "Unblock" button on the General Tab, click it, then go to the compatibility Tab
2. Tick the "run this file in compatibility mode" box and then select XP, or whatever OS the software was designed for, in the drop down box, Tick "run as Administrator" if it is available, hit OK
3. Now double click this setup.exe file to execute the install process, hopefully all will go well and install the Software you need.
4. Navigate to the program folder where it installed, then do the compatibility setting (step 1 & 2, skip run as administrator) again for the program executable(s). If the program was designed for Vista/W7 skip these steps.
   .